# Segfault Issues With Array of Structs Inside a Struct

Tags: c++, c, nested, segmentation-fault, structure

**Edit:** The first commenter reports that the code has no apparent errors, so I've revised the post with more code.  Apologies for the length.  Again the error appears to be when I reference the string vars in the substructure... note that if I remove the first write that causes the segfault in segfaults later on due to a write to the other string var.  Note that in this scenario other elements of the substructure (e.g. the `double Volume`) are correctly written without runtime error.

**Edit 2:**
As per Dave's suggestion, I ran Valgrind on the debugging enabled executable.  What it spit out was :

**Edit 3:** 
Apparently I had a version that malloc instead of a direct array inside the initializer.  Removing this fixed the problem.  I'll give Dave full credit for this one as valgrind is helping me fix all sorts of other memleaks/issues!  Thank you for your help, though....

Line 36 is the one it fails on (commented below)

*--code removed to prevent dissemination*

I declare an instance of my top level struct (sim_t) in main.  The program segfaults as soon as I try to write to the strings inside the substructure.  Writes to other vars of the substructure e.g. doubles, ints, etc. appeared to correctly execute when I ran the program in GDB.

It seems like there's something obvious I'm missing here.  Does anyone see the problem with this code?

(And for the record, please don't make comments about the capitalization, I'm following MSDN's naming convention standard.)

Comment: There's nothing at all wrong with what you've posted. More code.

Comment: Could you please provide the code which actually fails...

Comment: Just a guess - do you index into the string `InitialConfigPDB[1] = 'x'` without first providing some content to the string?

Comment: You may need to let us know, how you "write" to the string, any example code?

Comment: Hi guys, posted a ton more code... should help.  I was hesitant to post all of my source as this is for research, but I will edit out most of it once the problem is discovered, so no worries.

Comment: I'm running this on my machine with no problems. Could you run it in valgrind and see what it thinks?  $valgrind ./prog_name

Comment: alright, I think we're getting somewhere... Valgrind definitely sees a flaw on that line I'm adding to the post...

Comment: Try adding initializers for the string objects in box_s() --  
   InitialConfigPDB = ""; --
   PDBFileName = "";

Comment: @DavidMFrey: That's not necessary: the compiler automatically calls the default constructor for the `std::string` instances at the beginning of `box_s::box_s()`.

Comment: ok,  don't do it then... :)  I'm not actually a c++ programmer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding "boxX_start.pdb" to stringstream on every iteration without clearing the stream.  Memory usage could add up very quickly with a large NUMBEROFBOXES value.  Try this

```
void InitSimpleVars(sim_t & MySim)
{
  std::stringstream in;

  MySim.StartTime = clock();

  //INITIALIZE Box Sim Vars...                                                                                
  for (unsigned int BoxNumber = 0; BoxNumber < NUMBEROFBOXES; BoxNumber++)
    {
      in.str("");                                                                                           
      in << "box" << BoxNumber << "_start.pdb";
      MySim.Box[BoxNumber].InitialConfigPDB = in.str(); //SEGFAULT HERE, according to GDB                     
    }
}
```

adding in the in.str("");  to clear the stream. There may be a better way to clear it, but I'm not aware of it if there is.

Comment: Or, just declare `in` inside the for loop so that a new instance gets constructed and destroyed each iteration.

Comment: That's good advice, but that's not the problem.  It still segfaults on the line I commented, when I ran your revised code through GDB.  And check the update above, NUMBEROFBOXES is small -- 2.  Still thanks for the improvement! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're overflowing the stack.  If both `NUMBEROFBOXES` and `sizeof(box_t)` are somewhat large, then `sizeof(sim_t)` is going to be very large, and then even a single instance of `sim_t` will overflow your stack.

If you can't reduce `sizeof(sim_t)` in any way, then you'll need to allocate your object on either the heap (e.g. with `new`) or in static storage (e.g. as a global variable).

---

**EDIT**

I still suspect a stack overflow, but it's still hard to say at this point.  Run your program under GDB and run these commands and tell us what the results are:

```
$ gdb myprogram
(gdb) run
...
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
(gdb) bt
...
(gdb) list
...
(gdb) disas
...
(gdb) info reg
...
(gdb) info inferior
...
```

The last command gives you the PID of the program.  Then, from another terminal, run this command:

```
# Replace PID here with the PID of the program being debugged above
$ cat /proc/PID/maps
```

The information from these commands should help determine whether or not the problem is being caused by a stack overflow.

Comment: Oh I should add, that I had a previous version of this program that had all of these variables lose in the main function and it didn't overflow the stack.  Could putting them in a structure somehow cause a stack overflow?

Comment: sizeof sim_t with NUMBEROFBOXES == 2 is under 600 bytes

Comment: So that's not the problem either... hmm this is very strange :(  All of the comments so far have been good and addressed potential flaws elsewhere in the code, but following the given corrections still hasn't fixed the underlying flaw on that line.  Puzzling.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile this with `-Wall` do you perhaps get warnings about packing changes? I've had similar crashes due to `#pragma pack` before standard library headers.

Or, after some more looking at your code, perhaps change your `BOX1` and `BOX2` defines to 0 and 1, not 1 and 2 - given that your array has only 2 boxes.

Comment: +1 for the BOX1 and BOX2 defines.  That doesn't seem to be the issue according to your question, but will be an issue if the program makes it there.

Comment: I used `-Wall` and found some other issues elsewhere in my program which I fixed.  I also changed my constants to `0` and `1` as you suggested.  While the former #s would likely have caused issues elsewhere in the code later in execution, this did not fix the crash regarding those strings....  So +1 for good advice, but the mystery is still unsolved!

Comment: @Jason: Can you post a reproducible testcase? With includes and a main and so on? I don't think the error is in the posted code, and I could keep guessing (done a make clean? stack overflow elsewhere? inconsistent custom operator new? inconsistent defines/flags during compile? heap overflow that happens to corrupt the string instances?) but that would just be guesswork...

Comment: I may do that... check the valgrind profile above and see if that helps, first, though...

Comment: This is your real code? You don't happen to malloc() the actual struct?

Comment: Nope, that's the exact code, with the only absent parts being later calls that are in separate files and occur well after the segfault.  Check the valgrind profile above...

Comment: Valgrind indicates that the std::string constructor didn't ever run. How do you compile and link this? Have you tried to do a clean and rebuild

Comment: `g++ -Wall -g Main.cpp SimulationFunctions.cpp Init.cpp FinalOutput.cpp CalculateEnergy.cpp SimulationData.h Potential.h -o MC_Prog`  I'll try deleting the *.o files and see if that does anything

Comment: Tried it again, will all `*.o`, `*.gch`, and `*~` files removed... same error in valgrind.  I can send you the full code if you want to see it.... there's really not much more to it and that phase in the calls, though.

Comment: @Jason: Can you post the lot somewhere?

Comment: I would prefering to email you it (check my contact info), but worst-case I can put it in a pastebin and then pm you the location if you email me... It's 7 files (if you look @ the above compile command) so it's kinda large.

Comment: @Jason: Your contact info shouldn't and doesn't display email addresses :) Can you somehow reduce it to something that both breaks and compiles, then make it available to everyone following this question?

Comment: Actually you were right... see the update...it was a legacy file with a malloc... I'm doing conditional compilation, so I'm copying and pasting modules to their generalized names so there was a malloc/pointer in the actual code.  Case closed :)